# chessboard: creating and positioning a red king (new piece)

Tags: chessboard, skak

[image]

I need a *red king* here in the middle, that means a black king figure (piece), but in red color. He should have his own character, like 'R' (if possible). 
This is normally `\char"2654`

The handbook shows me a "hardcore method", which does not work for me. 
What do I have to do?

```
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass[margin=5mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\usepackage{skak}

% chessboard.pdf, p. 73:
%\cbDefineNewPiece[〈game〉]{〈color〉}{〈char〉}{〈on white〉}{〈on black〉}
\makeatletter
\cbDefineNewPiece{black}{M}% I am not allowed to use R'
{\raisebox{\depth}{\cfss@whitepiececolor
\char"2654}}
{\BlackEmptySquare%
\makebox[0pt][r]{\cfss@whitepiececolor
\raisebox{\depth}{%
\makebox[1em]{\char"2654}}}}
\makeatother   

\begin{document}
\setchessboard{showmover=false,
boardfontfamily={DejaVu Sans}% no effect....
}

\def\mylist{kd1, kd2, kd3, kd5, kd6, kd7,  
Ka4, Kb4, Kc4, Ke4, Kf4, Kg4, 
Md4% <-------   !
}
\setchessboard{setpieces=\mylist}
\chessboard
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you tru using `blackpiececolor=red`?

Comment: No, but if... I see no effect; and I need only the king in the middle to be red....

Answer (score 3):

By default a new piece will use the chess font, but you can switch to the normal text font or some other font in the definition:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\usepackage{skak}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
% chessboard.pdf, p. 73:
%\cbDefineNewPiece[〈game〉]{〈color〉}{〈char〉}{〈on white〉}{〈on black〉}
\makeatletter
\cbDefineNewPiece{white}{m}% I am not allowed to use R'
{\raisebox{\depth}{\cfss@whitepiececolor\normalfont
\char"2654}}
{\BlackEmptySquare%
\makebox[0pt][r]{\cfss@whitepiececolor
\raisebox{\depth}{%
\makebox[1em]{\normalfont
\char"265A}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setchessboard{showmover=false}

\def\mylist{kd1, kd2, kd3, kd5, kd6, kd7,
Ka4, Kb4, Kc4, Ke4, Kf4, Kg4,
md4% <-------   !
}
\setchessboard{setpieces=\mylist}
\chessboard
\end{document}
```

A new piece must have a new name and R is already taken. I would also suggest to stick to the convention to use lowercase letters for the black pieces.

[image]

Comment: So let us forget about the font for the moment. At this current problem, I only need kings - blacks, whites and a red one (and I think I can create 3 new pieces in my wish-font). So the main problem at your 'solution' is:  *The new piece (in the middle) is not correctly centered aligned.* Could you fix that?

Comment: look at the code. There is a `\raisebox{\depth}`. Btw: the other pieces are centered as they are special board chars with quadratic border. If you add normal chars you will have to fiddle with the position.

Comment: Aha, I have to use sth. like `\raisebox{1mm}` it seems...

Comment: Is it easy to fill that "new piece king" with white, as seen at the others?

Comment: you need a piece mask for this, that is something only good chess fonts provide. If you have black king you can try to color it in white and put behind the white king.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I will try.